# Route is not working for mongodb.. 404 not fou

Tags: post, http-status-code-404

> This is react  sign up component  used axious to post data ,but at post request requessted url is not found showing error 404 i checked everything but still its not working

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import './form.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

export const Signup = () => {
    const[name,setName] =useState();
    const[email,setEmail] =useState();
    const[password,setPassword] =useState();

    const handlClik=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post("http://localhost:3000/register",{name,email,password})
        .then(result=>console.log(result))
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))



    }

  return (
    <>
     <div className="form-container">
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <form onSubmit={handlClik} method="post">
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="signup-username"  onChange={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)}  name="signup-username" required/>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label >Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="signup-email"    onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)}  name="signup-email" required/>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label >Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="signup-password"     onChange={(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)} name="signup-password" required/>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  
    <div className="switch-form">
      Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
    </div>
  </div>
    
  </>
  
  )
}

export default Signup;
```

> This is node server.js file

```
const express=require('express');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const cors =require('cors');
const EmployeeModel=require('./Models/Employee'); 

const app=express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/employee');

app.post('/register',(req,res)=>{
    EmployeeModel.create(req.body)
    .then(employees=>res.json(employees))
    .catch(err=>res.json(err))

})
app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log("servr is running");
})

Error==>

Signup.jsx:14
```

> below error is showing mongo db compass is running live
> i tried many other thing like change port and restarting the server but still all methods is not working

```
       POST http://localhost:3000/register 404 (Not Found)
enter code here
```